# Oracle SQL Developer asking for password for "NoPasswordConnection":"TRUE"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to my company and to Oracle SQLDeveloper.
My colleague sent me a .json file with oracle connections used to access a database at my company. It has the following structure ( I have redacted the server and user name with "xxx"s)

{"info":{"role":"","SavePassword":"false","OracleConnectionType":"BASIC","serviceName":"xxxxprod","RaptorConnectionType":"Oracle","customUrl":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ora-surv-prod.xxxxx.com:<port_number>/xxxxx","oraDriverType":"thin","NoPasswordConnection":"TRUE","hostname":"oxxx..xxxxx.com","driver":"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver","port":"xxxx","subtype":"oraJDBC","OS_AUTHENTICATION":"false","user":"xxxx","KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION":"false","ConnName":"xxxx@ora-surv-prod.xxxxx.com"},"name":"xxxxx@ora-surv-prod.xxxx.com","type":"jdbc"
},

However, after I import the connections .json file using "import connection" and "Remove all passwords from the exported connections" .. I am still asked to provide username and password after running a sql query script.

When he had run it after importing the connections from a JSON, he didn't have to enter the password.

I import the connections json using "import connection" and choose "Remove all passwords from the exported connections" .. I am still asked to provide username and password after running a sql query script. (Screenshot attached).
When he had run it after importing the connections from a JSON, he didn't have to enter the password.

I am new to my job and I don't want to ask my colleague such a stupid question. What am I missing while importing the connections that is preventing me from accessing the database?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't make a connection without both a username and password and in the 3rd paragraph you state that you removed all passwords. So if you are to make a connection, you'll have to provide the required password.

Answer (score 0):

I am responding as there are no answers yet. While I probably don't have the complete solution to your problem, I hope my observations can guide you towards the full solution.

```
"SavePassword":"false",
```

A lot of things seem to be set as false, and the password does not seem to be there. So I am not sure if the file or procedure you followed is 100% correct. Check if the information provided inside is correct.

1. if there seems to be a problem with the json file, take the information (ex: connection name, etc.) and manually create the connection in SQL developer.
2. I know you said you don't want to ask you colleague such a "stupid" question but it's not a stupid one. Even company has its quirks in how a new person manages to get database access, so don't be afraid to ask your colleague for clarification.